# LG NetCast web app - Screen goes dim

Tags: smart-tv, lg

I made a hello world web app that overlays on top of input video, but after the app is open for a while the screen goes dim.

I figured it was because the content was is the same place the whole time. So now I am moving the content around the screen. That has had no affect.

The app is loaded off my USB memory stick, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same problem with some apps

Comment: @pgilmon , the closest thing I have got was to scale the the video object to something a few pixels under the full width.